# Number sign (#) in password for url

Tags: authentication, url, encoding

There is a special web service that was turned on for my company.
It has the url like http://11.0.0.39/.
My task is to login there and parse some data. It has an authentication popup window in which I should paste login and password.

[image]

My login is an ordinary name but password contains number sign symbol. It looks like **pass#ord**

I reviewed some questions about passing login/password data in url to overpass some additional authentication tasks and also there is a tip to encode special symbols with percent. So my link should look like:

```
url = "http://username:pass%23ord@11.0.0.39"
```

But unfortunately I cannot load this page neither with `requests` module nor even in Chrome. The popup window also appear every time I paste url with encoded password.
I can't understand what's wrong here, there were lots of similar cases with **@** sign and looks like login/password encoding helped there.

Comment: Are you sure that page is a HTTP authenticator? Check in your browser if it is not just a FORM, so you should provide form data

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the initial page remains the same when I type login/password

Comment: Look with your browser, developer tools. It may remain the same, but it could use cookies